# How to hide command prompt when using task scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have scheduled a task using task scheduler to run a python script. It works fine as but I don't want the command prompt to pop up every time program runs.

I cannot run as a system or use "run wheather logged in or not".

Tried doing it pythonw.exe but that works only if I run in admin mode for some strange reason. Can someone please help me finish this task, without admin privileges ? I'm stuck with this since days .